# How to get namespace of all packages installed in a salesforce organization?

Tags: apex, metadata-api

I want to fetch the namespace prefix of all packages installed in a salesforce organization.How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify the use case, but you can call the [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/)'s `listMetadata` on the Package object to get a list of installed packages, which will include the `namespacePrefix` attribute. You can't do this in, for example, an Apex Code trigger, but you could use regular Apex Code, JavaScript, or any other language that supports the metadata API call (e.g. Java, .Net).

Comment: any way to get the installed package version number using apex?

Comment: You could use [FF's Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to get this info, but not inside a trigger, at least not without a metadata cache.